# How to approach the TeX Live team with a feature request?

Tags: texlive, bugtracking

Or: **The output of `tlmgr --help` is ridiculously long. Is there anything I can do about it?**

I use TeX Live as my primary distribution and I often forget the exact commands that `tlmgr` uses. However, every time I call `tlmgr --help` I immediately regret, as it takes at least 30 seconds just to scroll through. The standard between modern CLI packages is that `--help` displays a short summary and everything else is either hidden under a subcommand (eg. `install --help`) or in `man`.

I would like to make a feature request about this, however I don't know how to start. I'm used to the modern FOSS development, where it is easy to reach the authors by filing an issue on GitHub or GitLab, and it is easy to submit and discuss a specific patch using Pull Requests. However, neither of these things seems to apply to TeX Live. They do have a [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source), but with Issues turned off, and the Pull Requests seem to be for technical fixes only. They have a [self-hosted SVN](https://tug.org/texlive/svn/), but I could not find an issue tracker.

I know they have a [mailing list](https://www.tug.org/texlive/lists.html), but I don't think I want to join it, because I'm not really interested in updates and discussions about TeX Live in general, I just want to discuss this one feature.

**Is there a way to contact the authors and talk about this feature request?**

Comment: well the way is to write to the mailing list. And you can always unsubscribe after the discussion again.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you want to talk to the authors but have said you don't want to use the mailing list?

Comment: On the 'issue' - the problem with `man` (at least for me) is that it's entirely Unix-centric, whereas `--help` works on all platforms and doesn't require additional hunting

Comment: @JosephWright Maybe I don't know how mailing lists work? Is a maling list specific to a issue/feature request, or will I recieve all mails about everything TexLive-related untill I unsubscribe?

Comment: I'm not even sure you need to subscribe. Probably you can simply send an email to the list address. I have sent a message once, and I don't remember having ever subscribed...

Comment: @campa you can simply sent, but answering to some feedback is then not so easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official route to contact the TeX Live maintainers is the 'main' mailing list, [`tex-live@tug.org`](https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live), which as noted in comments allows posts from non-subscribers. Other than some 'lost' users, who post general questions about (La)TeX to the list, the main volume is not too bad compared with some other places. As such, it's likely not too problematic to subscribe for the duration of a request: you are unlikely to get 100s of mails that way.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are looking for the summary that you get with `tlmgr -h`  rather than the full details from `tlmgr --help`

```
$ tlmgr -h

tlmgr revision 59291 (2021-05-21 05:14:40 +0200)
usage: tlmgr  OPTION...  ACTION  ARGUMENT...
where ACTION is one of:
 backup
 candidates
 check
 conf
 dump-tlpdb
 generate
 get-mirror
 gui
 info
 init-usertree
 install
 key
 option
 paper
 path
 pinning
 platform
 postaction
 recreate-tlpdb
 remove
 repository
 restore
 search
 shell
 update
 version

Use
 tlmgr ACTION --help
for more details on a specific option, and
 tlmgr --help
for the full story.
```

Comment: well that is a nice option, now we should make a feature request that `tlmgr --help` prints at the end "use tlmgr -h if you want a shorter help text" ;-)